# Wrong RGB values when converting from Bitmap

Tags: python, android, android-studio, opencv

I am making an android app that uses a tflite model to identify an image the model takes rgb values as an input so I am taking a photo as a bitmap and convert it to an rgb array but the conversion it gives me has wrong rgb values because when I tried to get the values on python using opencv it gives me different rgb values and the model on python works fine so I am mostly sure it is the wrong rgb values that make the model predict wrong in android
this is how I take my image

```java
final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imgURI);
Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
selectedImage = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(selectedImage,5,5,false);
selectedImage.setConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
img = convertToRGB(selectedImage);
```

and this is my convert to rgb function

```java
public int[][][] convertToRGB(Bitmap picture){
        int[][][] imgRGB = new int[picture.getWidth()][picture.getHeight()][3];
        for (int i=0;i<picture.getWidth();i++){
            for (int j=0;j<picture.getHeight();j++){
                int pixel = picture.getPixel(i,j);

                int R = (pixel >> 16) & 0xff;
                int G = (pixel >> 8) & 0xff;
                int B = pixel & 0xff;


                imgRGB[i][j][0] = R;
                imgRGB[i][j][1] = G;
                imgRGB[i][j][2] = B;
            }
        }
        return imgRGB;
    }
```

Comment: What means "wrong values"? Slightly wrong color or e. g. red and blue channels swapped?

Comment: it actually gives me drastically distant values

Comment: I just tried it on the same image the first pixel had these values 88, 102, 92 in opencv and 25 38 21 in android I dont know if the channels are swaped or not but I thought it was weird that the values are this different

Comment: As an aside-  don't use getPixel like that.  Hugely inefficient.  Use getPixels and get the entire image into an array.  It will run 4 or 5 times faster.

Comment: Why are you using createScaledBitmap?  What you'll get for data will entirely depend on the scaling algorithm used, which could be very different between the two.  Plus-  a 5 by 5 image?  That sounds wrong, unless this is meant to be a very trivial test case of something.

Comment: @GabeSechan the 5 by 5 image was for testing so I could see the entire rgb array I need to use the scaled map because my model accepts 320×180 images so I actually scale them to 320 by 180

Comment: @GabeSechan thanks for the advice I will use getPixels in my code then

Comment: If you're scaling them you will definitely see differences between this and another implementation.  Scaling is an algorithm, and the implementations can differ greatly.  For example, even createScaledBitmap takes a parameter to switch between two implementations.

Comment: @GabeSechan I see thank you for pointing this out but in python I use PIL libraries resize function with default params and after some research both it and scaled bit map use Nearest Neighbors as the default algorithm but it might have a dlfferent lmplementation of the algorithm